# Implicit wrap of Java Null

Tags: java, scala, null, implicit

I need to access a large set of Java interfaces from Scala.  These interfaces have methods that might return Null, and I want to convert them to `Option[T]`

I found other answers that describe `Option.apply()` like these

[How to implicitly wrap a value that can be null or an array into an Scala Option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10131873/how-to-implicitly-wrap-a-value-that-can-be-null-or-an-array-into-an-scala-option)

[Option-izing Java getters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10048403/option-izing-java-getters)

However, this requires that for each Java interface, I manually create a Scala wrapper.  Like this...

```
class ScalaFoo extends JavaFoo {
  def bar = Option(super.bar)
}
```

That seems messy, hard to maintain, and prone to error.  I don't want all that extra code that does nothing, and I want to automatically wrap all my Java interfaces, so that if one changes, the wrapper also changes.

Surely, there is a way to do this with implicits, isn't there?

Answer (score 3):

I recently ended up with something like this:

```
object Implicits {
  implicit class ConvertToOption[T](t: T) {
    def optional = Option(t)
  }
}
```

Usage:

Suppose you have a following Java interface:

```
public interface Fooable {
    public String getFoo();
}

public class Foo implements Fooable {
    public String getFoo() { 
        return null; 
    }
}
```

In your Scala code:

```
import Implicits._

val foo = new Foo()
val myOptionalValue = foo.getFoo.optional //returns an Option[String], in this case None because getFoo returns null
```

Comment: Thanks serejja, that's better.  I was hoping there was some way to wrap the whole interface so I (or others) can not make the mistake of calling getFoo directly.

Comment: I doubt you can achieve what you just said in a generic way. You have to manually write wrappers

Answer (score 3):

I'm not aware of a great way to do this either. However I saw a nice approach on twitter recently:

```
import Option.{apply => ?}
val fooBar = ?(javaFoo.bar)
```

Comment: Haha, nice one. And how about this? `implicit class ConvertToOption[T](t: T) { def ? = Option(t) }`. Results in `foo.getFoo?`

Comment: I like it! Less typing.  Although our Clojure friends may lament the lessened use of parentheses. :)